# Swift class error WKWebView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: swift, uiprogressview, addobserver

I have a problem removing observer from my viewController named "myBrowser". I have a ProgressView bar, Here is the code where i add the observer:

```
 webView!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .New, context: nil)
```

in this controller i have a button that let me go back to another controller:

```
@IBAction func disa(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

if i add

```
webView?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
```

inside disa func, my app crash because "WKWebView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it"...i tried put removeObserver in viewDidDisapper, in viewWillDisappear but my app still crash if i press the button before progressView bar is completely loaded.

How can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove observer in the `deinit` method

```
deinit {
    webView!.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
}
```

Comment: i'm using Swift...where i must put the code you posted? if i put it in the deinit method my app still crashes

Comment: Yes the same error. The error occurs when user tap "disa button" before ProgressView bar is fully loaded. (inside observeValueforKeyPath func i put this code: if webView?.estimatedProgress == 1{
                webView?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
            }

Comment: remove that 'if' statment and leave it only in deinit()

Comment: Done now...still same error! i don't know what to do!

Comment: can you show the full code of your viewcontroller, or at least all the code where you are using webview

Comment: Yes, i post it answering my question

Comment: posted now, please watch it

Comment: You can try to put it in the viewDidUnload method, not 100% sure if it's there in Swift (i'm still using Objective-C for UI stuff), but it almost has to be.

Comment: i tried...but if i write viewDidUnload i get this error, is marked as unavailable method :(

Comment: First, delete all addObserver statements and leave the one from viewDidLoad. Second, try to use: webView!.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress") , pay attention to the 'webView!' it's explicitly unwrapped, use it only in deinit()

Comment: Or you can use "#keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress)". For me this did a trick: `deinit {
        webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:  #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress))
    }`